# How to manage wx.StatusBar text in interactions with menus

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I have a main window with a `wx.StatusBar`, in what I think is pretty standard fashion:

```
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    "Obviously, the main window..."
    def __init__(self, parent, title, appState, installTypes):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title)

        # [...]

        # and StatusBar (which puts itself in the bottom of the window)
        self.CreateStatusBar()
```

I have a bunch of menus, which display their help in the StatusBar:

```
    # Auto-exit  toggle:
    menuOptionsAutoExit = optionsmenu.Append(ID_OPTIONS_AUTO_EXIT,
                                             _("&Auto-exit"), 
                                             _("Have CMH exit after showing the status"), 
                                             kind = wx.ITEM_CHECK)
```

But I also have events in my controller that need to be reported in the status bar.   Each of these has two actions that need to be done in the StatusBar: displaying the notification ("something is happening") then removing that.

The problem is that if the user is moused over a menu item (so that item's help has replaced "something is happening" in the status bar) at the time that I do the "remove the message", the result is that the removal is missed, and after they mouse off the menu item, I'm left with "something is happening" forever.

I've tried pretty much every combination I can think of of using either `SetStatusText()` or `PushStatusText()` to put "something is happening", and `PopStatusText()` or `SetStatusText('')` to clear it.   No matter what I do, by messing around with the menus in between setting the status message and clearing it I can end up with the "something is happening" stuck there.

What's the right recipe for this?

(wxpython 3.0.0.0, same behaviour under OSX and Win7)

Comment: I think you probably want the EnhancedStatusBar.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds exciting :)   Googling now...

Comment: I have some sample code, I'll try to track it down in a little bit if you don't find what you're after.

Comment: I pulled it down and ran the demo, but found it a bit discouraging.  I wonder if it has become out of date?  None of the demo screens lay out well - see screenie at    https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzeu7nn94zmvsf4/Screenshot%202014-10-17%2016.08.55.png?dl=0

Comment: @GreenAsJade you might want to consider AGWInfoBar or InfoBar they are both included with wxPython, check the demo for them.

Comment: InfoBar is great to know about.   It unfortunately brings with it resizing, which doesn't suit my app that well ... a much more desireable thing would be to actually be able to interoperate with the menu tooltips, but if I get desparate this might be the answer...

Comment: @Werner Actually, it is pretty cool - tweaking the settings I can almost get away with the resizing happening.   I'm still hoping for actual interoperation with StatusBar and menus, but InfoBar is a great backup - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of a work around but, might work for you.

```
self.CreateStatusBar(2)
self.SetStatusText("A Custom StatusBar...", 1)
wx.CallLater(10000, self.SetStatusText, "", 1)
```

So, do not use the first field on the statusbar for your messages.

Comment: (I didn't "accept" it yet because I'm really looking for genuine interoperation ... hoping for someone who knows the answer for that!)

Comment: I actually went with InfoBar, but you suggested that as well :)